# Getting error while deploying war in tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat9

This is details Log Context from tomcat log folder

30-Mar-2024 10:26:42.230 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [authenticationTokenFilterBean]
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [userService] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [userService].****
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:526)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:438)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:156)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4311)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4940)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1014)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1866)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:816)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1584)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:312)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)

On console:

```
30-Mar-2024 10:26:42.230 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
30-Mar-2024 10:26:42.246 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/NightLife-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
2024-03-30 10:26:42.261  INFO 8596 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-30 10:26:42.292  INFO 8596 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2024-03-30 10:26:42.292  INFO 8596 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-03-30 10:26:42.324  INFO 8596 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
30-Mar-2024 10:26:42.339 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [NightLife-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] appears to have started a thread named [mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```